# Trying to understand how to connect the most general concept of a function to real world?

Tags: mathematical-physics

I'm a beginner wrapping my head around how general a definition a "function" really is when connected to the real world, please help.

I am trying to connect the mathematical definition of a function to real-world occurrences. Here is the Wikipedia definition of "function":

> a function[note 1] is a binary relation between two sets that
> associates every element of the first set to exactly one element of
> the second set. (Wikipedia: Function (mathematics))

Say for example two rocks in space hit each other, can you consider that function?
Each rock has an input state: its mass, velocity, spatial position, etc. and each rock has a resulting output state after impact. Does that mean that the relationship between the two rocks throughout the collision can be considered a function?

If that is true can we then simply define a function as a relationship between objects?

If so and assuming determinism (let's not go down that rabbit hole) can you then view change in the universe as occurring due to a massive network of functions?

Or would it be a network of objects with the edges (of this imaginary graph) representing functions?

What is the best mental image here?

Can anyone recommend any good sources, where people consider these ideas at such a general and abstract level? (whilst still keeping the discussion grounded if possible)

Comment: Welcome to PSE! This questions seems pretty open ended and is lacking focus. Functions are used in many areas of physics, so there is not a unique interpretation. Additionally, you seem to be asking many questions here, some of which are subjective (such as "what is the best mental image here?"). Please try to focus your post into a single, objective question.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with your interpretation. First off, there are many types of specific functions but I am discussing them in their general form, that is input state leads to output state given a functional relationship. Second, all scientific diagrams and mathematical expressions are mental models put to symbolic form so that seems like a weird objection to me (though, true I used the word "images"). Finally, the nature of questions is to beget further questions, so that constriction that seems weird to me, especially in a scientific forum.

Comment: This is not a forum. This is a Q&A site with specific policies pertaining to the questions that are allowed.

Comment: A good basic calculus book will provide a coverage of functions sufficient for their use in basic physics applications.  I like any of the calculus textbooks by George B Thomas.  You can search for these on Amazon.

Comment: A good introduction to functions (at least, from a mathematical point of view) is done in Set Theory and Logic by R. Stoll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ denote a function. A function $y = f(x)$ associates a unique $y$ to every $x$.  Some functions have other properties such as: continuity, one-to-one, and onto.  A function is a special type of a relation.  A function can be defined for more than one variable; for example, $y = f(a, b, c)$ provides a unique $y$ for a specific set of $\{a, b, y\}$ values.

For example, the age of each of a set of persons can be described with a function; age = $f$(a specific person).  The cities served by a set of large airports cannot be described by a function, because each large airport serves more than one city- a relation can be used for this description.

Just as the mathematical construct of integers is used for counting discrete items, functions as defined mathematically describe a great deal of the real world (a couple of example follow below). Similarly, the mathematical construct of vectors describes many real world aspects of dynamics, such as the resolution of a force into components along different directions.  More complicated mathematical constructs have been developed, such as tensors to describe the inertia  for general motion of a rigid body and to describe the stresses in a solid or fluid.

For very many physical phenomena a function can be defined using an equation. Such a functional relationship allows us to quickly evaluate many of the variables of interest for a physical problem.  For example for an ideal gas pressure ,P, is a function of volume, V, number of moles, n, and temperature, T, $P = f(n, R, T)$; specifically $P = (nRT)/V$ where $R$ is a constant.  Another example is the exponential probability distribution function which provides the probability of failure, $P$, of a component within a given time, t, as the function $P(t) = 1 - \exp(-bt)$ where $b$ is the failure rate.

When a phenomenon can be described using a function, we can bring the entire mathematical properties of a function to bear for evaluating the problem.  For example, we can differentiate functions, integrate functions, etc.